# Добавить кнопку в панели админки woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-плагины

Хочу добавить еще одну кнопку в в разделе "заказы"(плагин woocommerce), должен быть такой же блок с кнопкой, как я могу это сделать? в woocommerce/templates/ ничего не нашел[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что за "кнопка", для чего? Исправь вопрос.

Comment: @SeVlad просто кнопка в верстке, которая будет иметь свой функционал (отправлять данные на сторонний сервис). Интересует сам факт добавления